# owl carousel play and stop buttons for multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I wanted to add a play/stop buttons to owl carousel. So far I managed to achive:

1. Added the play/stop buttons before owl-dots
2. Wrapped it all in a `div.controls` for better styling.

and this works well but only with one slider. When adding the next slider the code stops add the play/stop buttons without any errors in the consol.

I have tried to change the `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` but then I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertBefore')`

It would be perfectly if I could:

1. have multiple sliders with the buttons
2. modify if the play/stop buttons will be added before owl-dots or owl-nav for each slider

code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var owl = $('.slider__carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            margin: 15,
            animateIn: 'fadeIn',
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            dots: true,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true
                },
                700: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true
                },
                970: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true
                },
                1000: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true,
                }
            }
        });

        var owl = $('.logo-slider');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 1000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            margin: 15,
            dots: true,

            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 4,
                    nav: true
                },
                700: {
                    items: 2,
                    nav: true
                },
                970: {
                    items: 5,
                    nav: true
                },
                1000: {
                    items: 6,
                    nav: true,
                }
            }
        });

        var target = document.querySelector('.owl-dots');

        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.classList.add('controls');

        target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, target);

        wrapper.appendChild(target);

        document.querySelector('.owl-dots').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="owl-play-stop-btn"><a class="btn-play"><span class="visually-hidden">Play</span></a><a class="btn-stop"><span class="visually-hidden">Stop</span></a></div>');

        $('.btn-play').ready(function () {
            owl.addClass("hide-play");
        });

        $('.btn-play').on('click', function () {
            owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);
            owl.addClass("hide-play").removeClass("hide-pause");
        });

        $('.btn-stop').on('click', function () {
            owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
            owl.addClass("hide-pause").removeClass("hide-play");
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: You have to use different javascript variable names for both sliders. var owl = $('.logo-slider'); Change this variable name.

Comment: if I change the first slider to var baner = $('.slider__carousel'); baner.owlCarousel({ it still doesn't work